# How to draw a shape using cocos2d-android

Tags: cocos2d-android

I want to draw a rectangle shape using cocos2d-android . i googled all my way to draw the rectangle in my scene and trying

```
CGRect rect = CGRect.make(numbers[0][0],numbers[0][1],70,70);
```

but it was not displaying any rectangle. could any one help me out to draw a rectangle in scene?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the example file](https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/source/browse/trunk/src/org/cocos2d/tests/DrawPrimitivesTest.java?r=100) for drawing primitives. You can see an example of drawing a arbitrary polygon there:

```
// closed purple poly
gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
gl.glLineWidth(2);
CCPoint vertices2[] = {CCPoint.ccp(30, 130), CCPoint.ccp(30, 230), CCPoint.ccp(50, 200)};
Primitives.drawPoly(gl, vertices2, 3, true);
```

Just define your rectangle points there.

There are a lot more [test examples](https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/source/browse/?r=100#svn/trunk/src/org/cocos2d/tests%253Fstate%253Dclosed) to be found there that can answer the basic drawing questions like this.

Comment: can you plz elaborate the thing : how to make a handfree drawing ?